# Motherboard/Intel G43 Chip Overheating

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, desktop-computer

So I have a desktop PC and it is impossible for me to boot it up anymore. It boots up just fine but after between 5 to 30 seconds the central chip on the motherboard (Intel G43 Chip I believe) heats up really fast and restarts the computer. That is the only chip that heats up really fast and everything else is fine. I've tried stripping the PC to a bare minimum but the problem still persist. Any idea what could be going on with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but from your description it might be a broken chip>_< There is no good way to fix it other than replacing the whole motherboard.